# Check mapped drives in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, disk

I want to list all my disks with a .bat file to check if a network disk is connected or not.

I've made the next .bat file that works and shows me the physical and logial disks.

```
@echo off
wmic logicaldisk get caption,drivetype,providername
pause
exit
```

The question is: How do I check if it's connected or not? It possible to autoconnect in case the mapped disk is disconnected?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you mapping your drives?  If you're using Exploder, I am pretty sure they are already marked for persistence.  If you are using something like the `net use` command, then you should refer to the documentation for that tool.  Ultimately, I think you'll have to probe the drive to test whether you can physically connect to it.  Networked drives are notoriously fickle, so any indication that you're connected one instant, does not imply it will remain in that state.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the pattern in the sample below to return Connected or Disconnected mapped drives (or remove the piped portion all together to return all connections). As for reconnecting the drives, if they're disconnected, doesn't that mean its a network issue, since windows automatically reconnects them when the connection is available?

Batch Script (CMD):

```
wmic netuse list brief | find "Connected"
```

Powershell:

```
wmic netuse list brief | Select-String -Pattern "Connected"
```

Comment: CMD version fails to find mapped drives if running as Administrator. runas "a user" command fails as well. Yet, "runas "a user" net use" does find mapped drives. (Using Windows 11)